# How to assign client port in socket?

Tags: sockets, server, client, port

I am new to `socket` programming. So currently I'm doing `client-server` connection in my computer. So the `IP` address for both `client-server` is `127.0.0.1`. My question is, can I assign a specific client port to bind with the server? Instead of the `OS` chose the port number for me, can I assign it by myself? and if yes, can you help me on how to do this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a client use a specific source address with [bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), i.e. the same as you do for binding the server side address. But in most cases this additional effort is not worth it and might even result in troubles you did not had when using a system assigned port. Thus, don't do it unless it does not work without.

Comment: I see, now I get this. Thank you Steffen